# Holomorphic function assuming if minimum on the real line

Tags: complex-analysis

How "large" (in an appropriate sense) is the space of holomorphic functions attaining their minimum on the real line?
Best

Comment: by a rotation $f(\alpha z)$ you can move the argument of the minimum (or of any value) to any argument you want, in particular to the real line, so for any function, you find a rotated version with minimum on the real line, hence the question is kind of meaningless

Comment: Okay, thank you